# Is it possible to add a pair of radio buttons to MFC Ribbon bar?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, ribbon

Is it possible to add a pair of radio buttons to MFC Ribbon bar and how?

I could achieve the same with a check box, but strongly prefer radio buttons, becuase they give clearer clues to the user about the effects of the options.

Comment: If you know how to add a checkbox to a ribbon, then radiobuttons are no different. And to get the radiobuttons working together requires only the knowledge of how to get them working in a standard dialog.

Comment: I can just put a checkbox in theresource editor, while there is no radio buttons availible. In fact there is no such class lik e CMFCRibbonRadioButton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as far as I'm aware. The usual way is to simulate the behavior with check boxes. You need to manually control the behavior in the appropriate OnUpdate message handler:

```
void CC3SplicitView::OnUpdateToBe(CCmdUI *pCmdUI)
{
    pCmdUI->SetCheck(m_bToBe);
}

void CC3SplicitView::OnUpdateOrNotToBe(CCmdUI *pCmdUI)
{
    pCmdUI->SetCheck(!m_bToBe);
}
```